# Dropzone.js autoProcessQueue not working within Vue component

Tags: vue.js, dropzone

I'm using dropzone.Js inside a Vue component and I'm trying to submit the form in which the dropzone is only after submit button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropzone-js" class="col-md-12 control-label">Choose a profile picture:</label>
    <!-- even though there is not path in the action there is still a post request -->
    <form action="#"
     class="dropzone"
     id="dropzone-js"></form>
</div>
```

The print screen:

[image]

Vue component script:

```
 ready(){
  // I´ve tried to implement the autoProcessQueue to false in many ways, but 
  // withouth the desired result
  Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone").options.autoProcessQueue = false;
  Dropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = false;

  new Dropzone('#dropzone-js', {
    paramName: "profileImg", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    maxFiles: 1,
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log('event',event)

            console.log('accepted dropzone file', file)
            this.form.photo = file
            // done();
    },

    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file, event) { 
            // this.form.photo = file
            // alert("Added file."); 
            console.log('event',event)
        });
    },
    init: function() {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                    alert('Only 1 file allowed')
                    this.removeFile(file);
            });
    }
})
},
```

I'm still not sure what I'm missing here, but as it's the first time I'm using both, I'm quite lost on usage specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around, which I would guess is not recommended. If someone knows a better one, please comment.

I had to edit the dropzone.js source code and set the `autoProcessQueue = false`, like so:

[image]

I think the local setting of the dropzone object is not being able to override the global autoProcessQueue config.